# how to pull into multiple branches at once with git?

Tags: git

In a repo I have multiple branches, among them "master" and "develop", which are set up to track remote branches "origin/master" and "origin/develop".

**Is it possible to specify that I want both master and develop to be merged(fast-forwarded) at once?**

When I do `git pull` now I get something like this:

```
remote: Counting objects: 92, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (56/56), done.
remote: Total 70 (delta 29), reused 28 (delta 8)
Unpacking objects: 100% (70/70), done.
From scm.my-site.com:my-repo
   5386563..902fb45  develop    -> origin/develop
   d637d67..ba81fb2  master     -> origin/master
Updating 5386563..902fb45
Fast-forward
```

all the remote branches are fetched, but only the branch I'm currently on is merged with its corresponding remote branch.

So I have to do `git checkout master` ...

```
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 106 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

...and then `git pull` again, and then switch back to develop, to get the desired result.

I know I can make aliases/scripts that does these steps. <strike>But I want to avoid that if possible, as it is error prone and not very efficient</strike>.
Edit: ok let me rephrase that. My goal was not to discourage or frown upon script/alias customizing of git. I would just prefer a builtin solution if it exists :)

Comment: I tried `git pull origin refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` but that caused the remote master to be merged into develop..

Comment: Why would it be error-prone or inefficient? Git is intended to be customized like this. BTW, to avoid having to check out each branch, you may want to split your `pull` into a `fetch` followed by a `merge` into each branch.

Comment: @jjlin well if I can do it without checking out each branch that may help on the efficiency. It is error prone because the matrix of things that can go wrong and the effects it can have on the rest of the script is somewhat complex. I'm not saying it's infeasible to make it safe, but it would be a trade-off. So I'd prefer a builtin solution if it exists :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set up an alias that uses `git fetch` with refspecs to fast-forward merge your branches with just one command. Set this up as an alias in your user `.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    sync = "!sh -c 'git checkout --quiet --detach HEAD && \
                    git fetch origin master:master develop:develop ; \
                    git checkout --quiet -'"
```

Usage: `git sync`.

Here is why it works:

1. `git checkout --quiet HEAD` directly checks out your current commit, putting you into *detached head* state. This way, if you're on `master` or `develop`, you detach your working copy from those branch pointers, allowing them to be moved (Git won't allow you to move the branch references while your working copy has them checked out).
2. `git fetch origin master:master develop:develop` uses refspecs with `fetch` to fast-forward the `master` and `develop` branches in your local repo. The syntax basically tells Git "here is a refspec of the form `<source>:<destination>`, take `<destination>` and fast-forward it to the same point as `<source>`". So the sources in the alias are the branches from `origin`, while the destinations are the local repo versions of those branches.
3. Finally, `git checkout --quiet -` checks out the branch you were last on, regardless of whether or not there was a failure in the previous commands. So if you were on `master` when you ran `git sync`, and everything succeeds, you'll leave detached head state and check out the newly updated `master`.

See also [my answer to git: update a local branch without checking it out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/git-update-a-local-branch-without-checking-it-out/17722977#17722977).

Comment: I don't quite understand the detached-magic here, why can't the pointer to master be moved when develop is checked out? ...anyway I tried this, and it seems to work except now I get "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit."

Comment: ...which is solved the next time I pull

Comment: @Superole ***which branch*** is ahead of `origin/develop` when you use the alias? It wouldn't make sense if it was your local `develop` branch.  Also, the pointer for `master` ***can be moved*** if it's `develop` that is checked out, the point is that if it's `master` that is checked out, then you can't fast-forward `master` because that would affect your working copy, so that's why you detach the working copy from it first by using `git checkout head`. I saw another answer that described it as "standing on a rock", you have to get off the rock before you can move it.

Comment: it was indeed my local develop. And the reason must be that this fetch does not update the tracking branches. As I understand it; a pull will fetch into origin/develop, and then merge that into develop.

Comment: It is very important that this answer causes `fatal: bad config line xx in file xxx`. which is caused by the semicolon. you have to wrap the whole command in double quote to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 4):

```bsh
git fetch --update-head-ok origin master:master develop:develop
```

This is a shorter version of @40XUserNotFound answer, beware that it may move your HEAD, be sure you have a clean working directory before running this command.

`--update-head-ok` does what [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/627529/1144972) doing by detaching HEAD, instead it simply tells fetch it's ok to move HEAD (where your working directory is).

Comment: Cool! This looks like it's working! I wonder why they state in the docs that _this is purely for the internal use for git pull to communicate with git fetch, and unless you are implementing your own Porcelain you are not supposed to use it?_

Comment: I think it is because it might result in data lost, it moves the HEAD without checking if it in sync with upstream repo. But the provided answer does the same, so I think it is cool to use for this specific case

Answer (score 3):

Install [git-up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up). It gives you the command `git-up` which will pull all local branches in your repository.

Comment: sweet! I will check that out for sure.

Comment: heh :P The statements _Windows support is predictably absent._ and _a rigorous proof has yet to be formulated that it will definitely not mess with your git setup, delete data or post inane drivel to Hacker News on your behalf._, combined with the need for Ruby, drove me away. I like the concept though.

Comment: Glad there's a method _at all_ ... kinda sucky, though that every single method requires _some_ third-party tool. Such as this one and the ones with some shell command "recipe" or an alias making use of a particular (platform-specific) shell.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no builtin option for git to pull into multiple branches.
At least not in version 1.8.0. although [@Cupcake's answer](https://superuser.com/a/627529/167304) is close to it.

However [@jjlin's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/623217/how-to-pull-into-multiple-branches-at-once-with-git#comment775144_623217) made me realize that at least I don't need to pull twice.

So a slightly more efficient sequence would be:

```
git pull
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
git checkout -
```

Inevitably I ended up creating an alias, but decided to leave the pull out of it, and focused on just fast-forwarding a different branch.

```
[alias]
ffwd = "!_() { git checkout $1 && git merge --ff-only origin/$1 && git checkout -; }; _"
```

Of course, with no testing this alias assumes that I supply a valid name of a ff'able branch as 1st argument, and has undefined behaviour otherwise. It is also not optimal for use-cases with more than two branches, but it will get me what I need for now.

```
git pull
git ffwd master
```